# Hibernate Self join query wont parse to json

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, gson

I am using Hibernate to persist the data into a HSQLDB file.
I'd created a method similar to a tester and it "populates" and "query" the data that i'd stored.

But when i query the data, in debug mode it's like an infinite array something like:

Product (instance1 of product)
   -> ParentProduct (instance2 of product)
      -> ChildProduct (this guy is the same as instance 1)
And when i try to retrieve this as Json it breaks with a huge error:

```
com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beforeName(JsonWriter.java:618)
    com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:401)
    com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:527)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.write(TypeAdapters.java:310)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.write(TypeAdapters.java:295)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
```

Here's the source:

```
package com.thalesgomes.ws.rest.classes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Product parent;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Product> children;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Image> images;



    //Getters and Setters

}
```

And here:

```
package com.thalesgomes.ws.rest.JPA;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.thalesgomes.ws.rest.classes.Image;
import com.thalesgomes.ws.rest.classes.Product;

public class ProductJPA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        populateDatabase();
        getProducts();

    }

    private static void getProducts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EntityManager em = getManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        List<Product> products  = em.createQuery("from Product", Product.class).getResultList();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(products);
        System.out.println(json);
    }

    public static EntityManager getManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistence");
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static void populateDatabase() {

        List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
        Image img1 = new Image();
        Image img2 = new Image();

        Product parent = new Product();
        parent.setDescription("descriptionParent");
        parent.setName("nameParent");
        parent.setParent(null);

        Product child1 = new Product();


        img1.setProduct(parent);
        img1.setType("jpeg");
        images.add(img1);

        child1.setName("name1");
        child1.setDescription("description1");
        child1.setParent(parent);
        child1.setImages(images);

        Product child2 = new Product();
        img2.setProduct(child2);
        img2.setType("jpeg");
        images.add(img2);
        child2.setName("name2");
        child2.setDescription("description2");
        child2.setParent(parent);
        child2.setImages(images);





        EntityManager manager = getManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        try {
            manager.persist(img1);
            manager.persist(img2);
            manager.persist(parent);
            manager.persist(child1);
            manager.persist(child2);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Commit done.");
        manager.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd solved my problem using a Gson lib from Google.
I used the follow annotation:

```
@Exposed
```

At the ChildProduct entities, making the ChildProduct dont see the ParentProduct, but the ParentProdcut have visibility from ChildProduct.

The same goes to the Image entity, where the Image can't see the Product related to the itself, but the Product that holds the Image can see the Image.